# How to handle two different onSubmit functions in react-forms?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, redux-form

I have one grand-parent container where I have child component and inside that, another two child components.

This two child components are redux forms.

Now I want to handle both of these form submit events with form validations and perform different tasks. How can I achieve using redux-forms?

I tried using custom props, but that **doesn't** activate **form validations**.

Here is my code:

**ParentContainer:**

```
const props = {
 onSubmit: this.confirmChangeBillingInformation,
}
return <CompanyDetails {...props} />;
```

**Child component:**

```
const CompanyDetails = (props) => {
 <ChangePaymentInformation {...props} />

 <ChangeCompanyPricing {...props} />
}
```

**Grand child forms: There are two forms like this**

```
const ChangeCompanyPricing = ({ classes, companyPricing, showChangePricingModal, actions, handleSubmit }) => {
 return (
 ...
 <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
  <Button color="primary" type="submit" variant="raised">
    Save
  </Button>
 ...
 )
}
```

Comment: why can't you try child refs ?

Comment: @hrudaykumarreddy I'm very new to react. Can you please help with it?

Answer (score -1):

In Parent Container change the name of the variable as handleSubmit because in child components you are getting handleSubmit props in ChangeCompanyPricing component.It is not at all defined.So change it.In the confirmChangeBillingInformation do the validation.I assume all the data required for validation will be available to the parent component

```
const props = {
 handleSubmit: this.confirmChangeBillingInformation,
}
return <CompanyDetails {...props} />;
```

Comment: I'm using redux-forms. The code I specified is correctly working, I just want to segregate two different onSubmit calls.